# Easy to use, powerful wiki

Tags: software-development, document-management, wiki

,

Looking for an online wiki with at least the following characteristics, for use in a software team:

- normal wiki style links between docs/hierarchy
- login with Google/Microsoft ID
- and ability to allow no access/read/write access based on those IDs
- revision history on documents
- (optional) approvals required for changes on a subset of documents
- ability to comment and assign (as tasks) on parts of a document

Appreciate any tips.

Comment: [Dokuwiki](https://www.dokuwiki.org/dokuwiki#) and [MediaWiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki) are probably the most known

Comment: Maybe have a look at confluence https://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence

Comment: Does "online wiki" mean that you need a hosted wiki? Or do you just mean that it should be a web app (self-hosted), and not a local tool?

Comment: Hosted or self-hosted.  Either way, web app.

Answer (score 1):

[Dokuwiki](https://www.dokuwiki.org/dokuwiki#) seems to support both access control through [Access Control Lists](https://www.dokuwiki.org/acl) and login auth with third party account support through a [plugin](https://www.dokuwiki.org/auth)

It seems to have builtin [unlimited revision system](https://www.dokuwiki.org/attic) and [many other features](https://www.dokuwiki.org/features)

[Mediawiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki) also supports revisions, and [multiple auth plugins](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/OAuth) as well. Most other features can probably be achieved with installation of [extensions](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Category:Extensions)